# Mutable Strings in Swift

Tags: swift

Okay, so I was hoping to `NSRegularExpression`'s find and replace methods to edit a `String` in Swift, however I can't pass it in directly to these as it's not considered to be of the `NSMutableString` type, even when declared via `var` (which enable's `String`'s mutating methods).

So my only workaround so far is:

```
var theString = "foo bar"
let theExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "f..", options: nil, error: nil)!

var theStringWithReplacements = NSMutableString()
theStringWithReplacements.appendString(theString)

theExpression.replaceMatchesInString(theStringWithReplacements, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, theStringWithReplacements.length))

theString = theStringWithReplacements
```

This is fine for smaller strings, but I'm concerned it won't be great with really big pieces of text, which I'd much rather modify a properly mutable string, rather than via a mutable copy.

Is it possible to this with a Swift String directly, or am I stuck using an `NSMutableString` copy for the time being, or working entirely with them where I need to?

My only other alternative seems to be to use `theExpression.matchesInString()` and perform the replacement using the ranges it gives, converted to work along with `theString.replaceRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

This cruft works for Swift 2.2 Foundation / Cocoa awkwardness, which should be better in Swift 3.0+:

```
    do {
        let theExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "f..", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let mutableStr = theStringWithReplacements.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString
        if theExpression.replaceMatchesInString(mutableStr, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSRangeFromString(theStringWithReplacements), withTemplate: "your new string here") > 0 {
            // success
            theStringWithReplacements = tmp as String
        } else {
            // failed: regex didn't match
        }
    } catch {
        // ignored: NSRegularExpression regex pattern assumed to be correct
    }
```

Probably easier to use `stringByReplacingMatchesInString`

```
    do {
        let theExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "f..", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        theStringWithReplacements = theExpression.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(theStringWithReplacements, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSRangeFromString(theStringWithReplacements), withTemplate: "your new string here")
    } catch {
        // ignored: NSRegularExpression regex pattern assumed to be correct
    }
```

**Bonus:** Here's a String extension to make regexes a little easier (matching is similar)

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    // returns nil if pattern is bad, or a copy of self with any replacements
    func replaceMatches(pattern: String, regexOptions: NSRegularExpressionOptions = NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0), matchOptions: NSMatchingOptions = NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSRange! = nil, template: String) -> String! {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: regexOptions)
            return regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(self, options: matchOptions , range: range ?? NSRangeFromString(self), withTemplate: template)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no regular expression options, the easiest I can think of is:

`theString.stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString("f..", withString: "goo", options:.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)`

Of course, this is technically bridging to `NSString` in the background, which Apple may convert to `NSMutableString` behind the scenes. Pure Swift (as in not importing even `Foundation`), there is nothing in the standard libraries.